# Unity3D/Blender: Obj shows submesh with incorrect origin/pivot ? How to set?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, wavefront

I have a model of a drone which was exported as all 1 mesh. My goal is to separate out the props so that they can animate/spin correctly. As such I have an obj which was exported from blender with 1 submesh. However, when it gets imported into Unity, the submesh's vertex data is from the perspective the root parent origin rather than a new frame of reference for the submesh.

I have tried changing the origin in blender, exported with various group options, but I can't seem to find the magic step so that the Unity3D pivot matches the blender origin.

[image: Blender]
[image: Unity3D]

Note: I am aware that I can modify the scene graph in Unity3D itself, but due to other tools requirements, I can not, and thus hoping to get a hint on how to fix the data side.

Comment: I had the same kind of problem and I used 3D Builder on windows to move and set the pivot myself. Not a clean way of solving this issue but if you are in a rush...

Answer (score 0):

Origin of the models exported from blender is set to the center of scene. In blender set your propeller to the center of the scene and apply location with `Ctrl+A`, and then export.

Comment: This is not useful though, because that just shoves all submeshes at the origin of the scene which is wrong... the submeshes are their own coordinate frame, not in global space. The vertex data needs to be exported with the origin at the prop's center, which is where I have it in blender (in pic)

Comment: I think this can be done only with blender/unity scripting. Default export behaviour set origins at scene center. Unity script should move all vertices in mesh regarding to pivot parameter in script. You can try [this](https://solvethesystem.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/solving-the-pivot-problem-in-unity/)